# "End of Central Directory record could not be found" in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to add some below reference files to my existing project

```
 <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads" version="60.1142.0" targetFramework="monoandroid80" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite" version="60.1142.0" targetFramework="monoandroid80" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="60.1142.0" targetFramework="monoandroid80" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gass" version="60.1142.0" targetFramework="monoandroid80" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks" version="60.1142.0" targetFramework="monoandroid80" />
```

When I add the above packages and rebuild the project, I got the below exception

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       End of Central Directory record could not be found.
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
   at Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore.LoadResource(String resourceFullPath, String assemblyName)
   at Xamarin.Build.Download.BaseXamarinBuildResourceRestore.MergeResources(IAssemblyResolver resolver, String originalAsmPath, String mergedAsmPath, String assemblyName, List`1 resourceItems)    iPro
```

When I remove the above reference, it works fine. How to solve this issue.

Comment: I think you could try to use Nuget manager in vs to install those packages

Comment: I am using Nuget only to install  the packages. All references were installed properly by when I build the project then the error occurred that what I described above. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is there any bug with Oreo SDK Compiler?

Comment: Have you try to clean and rebuild the project? And does this problem also happen to other project?

Comment: @Billy Yes, I tried clean and rebuild. I tried by creating a fresh new project but I got the same error. Although I uninstalled the Oreo SDK and targeted to Nougat SDK that works fine.

Comment: @Amit - did you get a solution to this? We're getting a similar problem with a newly installed Visual Studio/Xamarin build.

Comment: @James - I couldn't able to find the root cause but what I had done is : Created a new project and took all the references to its latest update.

Comment: Similar to your solution - we found it was almost definitely due to security/proxy settings causing zip files to not download correctly. Temporarily removing the proxy/firewall solved the problem.